# как мне анимировать эту png картинку, чтоб при наведении валики передвинулись направо так чтобы был эффект рисования

Tags: html, css

Пробовал разделить картинку на 3 фрагмента и с помощью hover как ни будь создать эффект появления, но что-то пошло не так, помогите кто знает )) [image: все делается через HTML, CSS но можно и js если по другому никак]

Comment: И где то что вы пробовали ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вариант.

Берем блок делаем ему ширину и высоту, закрашиваем его полоской от краски.
Валик отдельной картинкой используем для фона псевпоэлемента before. При этом нужно закрасить before в цвет фона и поверх фона налепить картинку валика. (так сделать можно при помощи background-color и background-image, а при наведении на наш блок сдвигаем before на нужное нам расстояние и таким образом получится нужный эффект.

Вот код самой идеи реализации.

```
<div class="wrap"></div>

  .wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
  }

  .wrap:before {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
  }

  .wrap:hover:before {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
```